# Appending to a CSV file after obtaining datum from a database

Tags: mysql, csv

I can [finally] extract data from the MySQL DB

```
my_database_query="SELECT * FROM my_database.database"
mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD' << EndOfFile
$my_database_query
EndOfFile
```

How can I append this to `myfile.csv`?

Comment: Probably change the second line to `mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD' << EndOfFile >> myfile.csv`.

Comment: @scott Thanks, though it ended up being `mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD' >> myfile.csv << EndOfFile `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` command is the thing that actually generates the output,
so redirect its standard output (stdout).  Change the second line to

```
mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD' >> myfile.csv << EndOfFile
```

using `>>` to append to `myfile.csv`, if it already exists.

Comment: I still believe that `mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD' << EndOfFile >> myfile.csv` should work just as well.